# Is there a reliable JSON Schema validator library which can be used easily in the browser (script src) and by Node.js?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

Most libraries, it seems, do not support easy use in browsers. Isn't there a reliable JSON Schema validator library which I can load into my browser  just as easily as many other libraries?

It would be extra great if it was available as a Node.js module for the back-end. I just want to check some schemas. Does anyone know if this exists anywhere?

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a list of [JSON Schema implementations here](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validator-javascript). If you know of others, please open an issue or pull request!